# Western Digital Mybook is creating folders I didn't create

Tags: windows-explorer, external-hard-drive

I have a WD MyBook which has been creating empty folders with a long string of numbers and alphabets and some shorter ones with just some numbers  with a 0kb file in it

Some of these can be deleted but some just stay put. It's irritating to find new ones everyday and now i have a collection of them which don't delete is there any way to delete these ?

**Edit:** I have scanned the drive using Antivirus and AntiMalware Software so i don't think it would have a virus

---

*One solution is copying all the matter elsewhere and formatting the hard disk but there is not guarantee that these folders wont reappear.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Windows creating unknown alphanumeric folders in my external drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/1367411/how-to-stop-windows-creating-unknown-alphanumeric-folders-in-my-external-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatted the Hard Drive as there was no real solution after a long time.