# How to stop Windows creating unknown alphanumeric folders in my external drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive, filesystems, temporary-files

I posted similar [question](https://superuser.com/q/1360257/475817) and accepted an answer as Visual Studio installation can left behind these files as documented but there is more to it.

I haven't installed any Microsoft product but I keep getting more and more of these alphanumeric folders which are all empty on almost daily basis. I can't just delete them every day, it is hard to locate my own folders in the jungle of folders it creates.

How can I stop Windows from creating these folders or more precisely to make it delete them when its done with them?

[image]

Comment: Are those folders' contents identical?

Comment: They are all empty. The size of all this folders is zero bytes but they are just there and keep growing.

Comment: How frequently do they appear? Can you sit and wait until one appears while having [procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) running?

Comment: @grawity Well the screenshot I post about 20 minutes earlier shows 99 items and now its 100 so one folder has apprently added during this time.

Comment: @grawity I have started running procmon and will monitor the count of folders in explorer periodically if it changes again but Its probably hard to catch right at the time of creation.

Comment: @grawity Ok have deleted all these folders so I would know when a new one gets created and what's the name. I can then search that in procmon which is running but what after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Finding root cause

1. Run a file system monitor tool (e.g. [ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)) and wait for folder to appear.
   Make sure to run it as administrator to capture more details (right click -> "Run as Administrator"). 
   In case of ProcMon, enable only "Show file system activity", and disable others (registry, network, etc).
   [image]
2. Once folder appears, search the folder name in ProcExp to see which process created it.
3. After finding out the process name, double click on it, to see details.
   [image]

### Possible causes

1. Misconfigured software - try to remove/disable or reinstall the software, or configure the software itself. This is wast case, purely depends on the software, can vary from reverting last OS update to configuring services/tasks. (Will give hints once you tell exact process name)
2. Malware - then scan that process file(s) with antivirus software. If there is no antivirus software installed, try online ones like [VirusTotal](http://virustotal.com) (which scans file with 50+ different antivirus software at once).
3. Software bug - try to report to software company.

These steps at least will give you universal starting point for investigation. 
(Will update answer once you give more info - like process name).

### Fallback solution

Here is a fallback workaround (if its a bug and software developers don't seem to fix it). It will remove top-level empty folders in the specified path.
1. Create a text file with following contents, name it `removeEmptyFolders.bat`

```
set PATH=f:\*
for /d %%1 in (*) do rd "%%1"
```

2. Run it to remove those folders at once. Or, put it on Windows program auto-start location, as described [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/). Then it will automatically remove empty folders after each restart.

Note: Make sure to test it first on other folder, by giving other `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, I let the ProcMon run overnight and I had two new folders created this morning. Search in ProcMon shows they are created by MozyEnterprise so now I know.

Comment: @zar Welcome. You marked this as answer, is your problem solved now? If yes - what did you do with MozyEnterprise to solve it? (Remove/reinstall/configure?) If no - then I can give more hints.

Comment: I marked it answered because at least I know what is causing it. I did check options in Mozy but can't see what to change to resolve this. I am thinking of it more like a bug but please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall it? By the way, added a workaround into answer.

Comment: I might do that at some point but I don't have high hopes from reinstall.